# Add comma after every 3rd character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a varchar column for *CCodes*- it's a string of 60-character where every 3 digits is a CCode.

Example:

```
149001006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This translates to following CCodes: 149, 001, 006, 000, ..

I would like to query this to find certain CCode(s) (example 347).

I can't use "like" keyword because they may be *shifted* (example 003470111 - this does not qualify because that translates to 003, 470 and 111 and none is 347)

Additionally I'd need it to work in a select statement and preferably not using a user-defined function (due to performance; it's a large table).

My current solution (my colleague's actually) uses stuff() to add comma after every 3rd character then string split them (comma as delimiter).
With this we use the cross apply to get the split CCode.

Example:

```
select ccode = splitcodes.value
from ...
cross apply string_split(stuff(stuff(... (CCodes, 4, 0, ','), ...), ',') as splitcodes
```

I'm wondering: **Is there a better way?**
Thank you.

Comment: Why not fix the design? Also, why are you against UDFs? Only poorly designed UDFs perform poorly (just likely poorly designed databases). The design is the problem here, so you are by choice choosing for less performant options.

Comment: Define better? How would you know an alternative solution was an improvement?

Comment: Assuming that a fix to the schema will be received positively, why not add delimiters at the time of insert or update? Then you could use LIKE. That will not be an efficient approach but it can be considered "easier" and consistent with the approach you seem to be taking.

Comment: Since you're using `String_Split` the order of the CCodes is not significant. Are the repeated `000` values meaningful or just padding to maintain a constant length? Can other CCode values repeat?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @EightChickens - Do you actually need to modify the data with the 3 commas or just be able to find the rows that contain the "triad" data you're looking for?

Comment: Hi. @ Larnu - I can't fix the design because it's a 3rd party vendor's table.
@ Dale K - Alternative that has less "hardcoded" and repeated "stuff()", if possible.
@ Jeff Moden - I don't need to modify the data; Just need to "split" the string.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you need to split the stored 60-character string at every 3rd character to find a substring (*CCode*) with specific value and this is different from the question's title (*"Add comma after every 3rd character"*). So, if this is the case and if the string has a maximum length of 60 characters, you may use a tally table with 20 (60/3) rows in the following way:

```
SELECT d.CCodes
FROM (VALUES
   ('149001006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
) d (CCodes)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
   (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), 
   (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19)
) a (N)
WHERE SUBSTRING(d.CCodes, a.N * 3 + 1, 3) = '001'
```

Of course, if you want to select the rows if a specific substring (`CCode`) exists, you can use the following statement:

```
SELECT d.CCodes
FROM (VALUES
   ('149001006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')
) d (CCodes)
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM (VALUES
      (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), 
      (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19)
   ) a (N)
   WHERE SUBSTRING(d.CCodes, a.N * 3 + 1, 3) = '149'
)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Add comma after every 3rd character

One approach is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), '') as str, convert(varchar(max), ccode) as rest, ccode
      from (values ('149001006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')) v(ccode)
      union all
      select concat(str, ',', left(rest, 3)), stuff(rest, 1, 3, ''), ccode
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select stuff(max(str), 1, 1, '')
from cte
group by ccode
```